# Requirements Elicitation Technique For Unknown Workflow

Tags: requirements, meetings, business-analyst

What elicitation technique(s) would you use for a workflow-dependent feature, where the workflow is largely unknown? Given a workshop with the primary user,the designer, the developer and the BA (me), what is the best tool for the job?

**Context:** We are working on the first release of a large-scale agile project. During a recent sprint planning, it became clear that stakeholders are not all on the same page regarding the requirements of a specific feature. The feature is part of an interface that will allow our content managers to preview web pages in different states and across different times. Since the concept of scheduled content is new to this release, there is a question of what the workflows will look like (and by extension how content managers will use the feature).

Comment: You can't do one without the other. Do User Story Mapping to define the context for your features.

Comment: Who are the stakeholders?

Comment: Stakeholders are the primary user, the head of development and the head of design.

@CodeGnome do you want to post that and I'll mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use "User Story Mapping"

To define features that depend on workflow, you first have to *map* the workflow. One of the more modern agile techniques for defining workflow, and workflow-dependent features, is the User Story Map.

A good map will contain both workflow and the stories associated with each *journey* within the story map. For your purposes, the journeys are the most likely equivalents to the workflows you're searching for.

### Resources

- [Story Mapping Quick Reference](http://jpattonassociates.com/story-mapping-quick-ref/) in PDF format
- *[User Story Mapping: Discover the Whole Story, Build the Right 
  Product](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033851.do)* by Jeff Patterson
- [Blog post](http://jpattonassociates.com/the-new-backlog/) on User Story Mapping

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily managed with a meeting with the stake holders and the technical team. At the time of requirement gathering (before finalizing the scope of the project) the technical team needs to get an A to Z picture of the project and needs to come up with the queries that they have in a document and then go for a phone call/brainstorming section with the stakeholders and prepare the modules/features list and get it approved on the same. Then stick-on with these features as final and if they ask for change/modification consider them as a new scope.